# Changing the label color on a Pie Chart using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace to generate a pie chart and I got it to do mostly what I want.  The Theme I'm using has the following code:

```
public static class ChartThemes
{
    public const string Blue =
    @"<Chart ForeColor=""#ffffff"" BackColor=""#0000ff"" BackGradientStyle=""TopBottom""         BackSecondaryColor=""White"" BorderColor=""26, 59, 105"" BorderlineDashStyle=""Solid"" BorderWidth=""2"" Palette=""none"" PaletteCustomColors=""#0000FF; #0055ff; #5599ff;"">
    <Titles>
        <Title ForeColor=""#ffffff"" Name=""main"" Font=""Arial Black, 16pt, style=Bold"" />
    </Titles>
    <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""64, 165, 191, 228"" BackGradientStyle=""TopBottom"" BackSecondaryColor=""White"" BorderColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"" BorderDashStyle=""Solid"" ShadowColor=""Transparent"">
            <AxisY LineColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"" TitleForeColor=""#ffffff"" TitleFont=""Arial Black, 8pt"">
                <MajorGrid Interval=""Auto"" LineColor=""#00ff00"" />
                <LabelStyle Font=""Trebuchet MS, 16pt, style=Bold"" ForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX TitleForeColor=""#ffffff"" TitleFont=""Arial Black, 8pt"">
                <LabelStyle ForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
                <MajorGrid Interval=""Auto"" LineColor=""#ff0000"" />
            </AxisX>
            <AxisX2>
                <LabelStyle ForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
            </AxisX2>
            <AxisY2>
                <LabelStyle ForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
            </AxisY2>
        </ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <Legend _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Transparent"" Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" IsTextAutoFit=""False""  ForeColor=""#ffffff""/>
    </Legends>
    <BorderSkin SkinStyle=""Emboss"" />
  </Chart>";
}
```

Then I'm generating my pie chart like this:

```
public ActionResult PieChart()
{
     var chart2 = new Chart(width: 600, height: 600, theme: Helpers.ChartThemes.Blue).AddTitle("Pie Chart","main")
    .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Pie", xValue: new[] { "Pizza", "Hamburgers", "Hot Dogs" }, yValues: new[] { 20, 20, 60 })
    .AddLegend()
    .GetBytes("png");
    return File(chart2, "image/png");
 }
```

I then get a chart that looks like:

[image: Blue Pie Chart]

The problem is that I don't want the labels that appear on the pie segments themselves to be black, I want them to be white.  However, I cannot find much documentation on how to do it in XML or any other way.

So my question is how to do I use the XML to change the color of the labels on the segments of the pie itself (the ones that appear black in the picture)?

Comment: What is your question exactly? ;)

Comment: @sunnysidedown916 my bad it should be cleared up now.  But basically I want to change the labels on the pie segments  themselves (the black ones) to another color.  I'm just kind of playing around with the charts right now so it doesn't matter the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  What I had to do was add a series to the XML.  To do this I had to know the name of the series and I know that because when I called the `AddSeries` method on `chart2` the first parameter is its name and therefore my series name is `Default`.

So the next step I took was to add a series open tag and a series end tag before `ChartAreas`.  In between teh series tag I added another series tag that had the `Name` and `LabelForeColor` properties like so:

```
<Series Name=""Default"" LabelForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
```

If you wanted to add more properties you could by [using the properties listed in this Documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series(v=vs.110).aspx)

So the end XML looked like:

```
@"<Chart ForeColor=""#ffffff"" BackColor=""#0000ff"" BackGradientStyle=""TopBottom"" BackSecondaryColor=""White"" BorderColor=""26, 59, 105"" BorderlineDashStyle=""Solid"" BorderWidth=""2"" Palette=""none"" PaletteCustomColors=""#0000FF; #0055ff; #5599ff;"">
    <Titles>
        <Title ForeColor=""#ffffff"" Name=""main"" Font=""Arial Black, 16pt, style=Bold"" />
    </Titles>
    <Series>
        <Series Name=""Default"" LabelForeColor=""#ffffff"" />
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
    //... and so on and so forth
```

This was the resulting image:

[image: White Label Pie Chart]

I figured this out with help from [This blog post](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-set-change-chart-series_3820.html).  I noticed that they were changing the series color so I figured something similar in the XML would do the trick.

Comment: Awesome! :) Good job! :D